# SSH Tunnel from Work local server to Home computer

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

We have server at the office that I can access it only from the local wifi just by ssh into it: `ssh@192.168.111.111` . Also if I type `192.168.111.111` in the browser, it will show me the phpmyadmin interface which is apparently set on port 80.

I often need to work from home including some simple server side work (I'm not proficient with linux, but I can do simple stuff). So I need to open ssh tunnel to my home machine (or from my home machine... not sure).

My work ip is `201.222.222.222` and my home ip is `230.333.333.333`.

My guess is that to achieve what I want, I need to run this command on the server.
`ssh -R remote_port:local_address:local_port username@server.com`

`ssh -R 8080:192.168.111.111:80 root@230.333.333.333` - would this command typed on the server at my work do the trick and allow me to ssh into it using port 8080 or do I completely miss the logic? (if yes, could you suggest the right workflow)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your SSH server has access to 192.168.111.111 try this:

`ssh -L 8080:192.168.111.111:80 user@201.222.222.222`

then you can open `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser. You should see phpmyadmin.